# How to display HWB/HSB/CMYK channels using RGB or HSL

Tags: javascript, colors, html5-canvas, color-picker, hwb

I am trying to display each color channel for different color models, similar to [this site](http://colorizer.org/).

That site displays HSB and CMYK but I would also like to show HWB.

For displaying RGB and HSL I obviously just used `rgb()` and `hsl()`.
For example, to display the full range of s(aturation) in hsl I would do something like this:

```
hsl(hue, 0, luminosity);
hsl(hue, 50, luminosity);
hsl(hue, 100, luminosity);
```

Apply that to a linear gradient and then display on canvas. It seems [addColorStop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value) only supports keywords, hex, rgb/a and hsl/a. So how can I visually represent the other color models using the ones available?

I've looked everywhere and can't find anything, hopefully this isn't a duplicate question.

Comment: I'm curious, who makes the downvotes for the such questions!?

Answer (score 3):

> **Update 2023:** Now HWB has full support. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/hwb#browser_compatibility

HWB is not supported in the browser or canvas at the moment. It's included in CSS module level 4, but not supported anywhere yet.

It's easy to convert to and from the color model though.

I converted these JavaScript functions to convert between RGB and HWB from [this code](http://alvyray.com/Papers/CG/hwb2rgb.htm) (with some adjustments to normalize H and "de-normalize" RGB). They both return an object:

```js
// RGB [0, 255]
// HWB [0, 1]
function rgb2hwb(r, g, b) {
  
  r /= 255;
  g /= 255;
  b /= 255;
  
  var f, i,
      w = Math.min(r, g, b);
      v = Math.max(r, g, b);
      black = 1 - v;
  
  if (v === w) return {h: 0, w: w, b: black};
  f = r === w ? g - b : (g === w ? b - r : r - g);
  i = r === w ? 3 : (g === w ? 5 : 1);

  return {h: (i - f / (v - w)) / 6, w: w, b: black}
}

// HWB [0, 1]
// RGB [0, 255]
function hwb2rgb(h, w, b) {
  
  h *= 6;
  
  var v = 1 - b, n, f, i;
  if (!h) return {r:v, g:v, b:v};
  i = h|0;
  f = h - i;
  if (i & 1) f = 1 - f;
  n = w + f * (v - w);
  v = (v * 255)|0;
  n = (n * 255)|0;
  w = (w * 255)|0;

  switch(i) {
    case 6:
    case 0: return {r:v, g:n, b: w};
    case 1: return {r:n, g:v, b: w};
    case 2: return {r:w, g:v, b: n};
    case 3: return {r:w, g:n, b: v};
    case 4: return {r:n, g:w, b: v};
    case 5: return {r:v, g:w, b: n};
  }
}

// ------ TEST -------
var hwb = rgb2hwb(250,100,10);
var rgb = hwb2rgb(hwb.h, hwb.w, hwb.b);
document.getElementById("hwb").innerHTML = hwb.h.toFixed(2) + "," + hwb.w.toFixed(2) + "," + hwb.w.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("rgb").innerHTML = rgb.r + "," + rgb.g + "," + rgb.b;
```

```html
Original RGB: <span>250,100,10</span><br>
rgb2hwb: <span id="hwb"></span><br>
hwb2rgb: <span id="rgb"></span><br>
```

To use it as a input for a color-stop etc., do something like this:

```
gr.addColorStop(n, fromHWB(360, 50, 50));
...

function fromHWB(H, W, B) {
    var c = hwb2rgb(H/360, W/100, B/100);
    return "rgb(" + c.r + "," + c.g + "," + c.b + ")"
}
```

Comment: There's a bug in `rgb2hwb` caused by using the same name for the variable blackness as for the argument blue - `b`. In the line `f = r === w ? g - b : (g === w ? b - r : r - g);`, the `b` is supposed to refer to the argument blue, but it is shadowed by the variable blackness.

Answer (score 1):

Support for HWB(*hue whiteness blackness*) was [added in Chrome 101](https://blog.chromium.org/2022/03/chrome-101-federated-credential.html) in 2022.

The specifications are listed in the [CSS Color Module Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#the-hwb-notation):

Implementation:

`hwb() = hwb( [<hue> | none] [<percentage> | none] [<percentage> | none] [ / [<alpha-value> | none] ]? )`

```js
function hwbToRgb(hue, white, black) {
    white /= 100;
    black /= 100;
    if (white + black >= 1) {
        let gray = white / (white + black);
    return [gray, gray, gray];
    }
    let rgb = hslToRgb(hue, 100, 50);
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        rgb[i] *= (1 - white - black);
        rgb[i] += white;
    }
    return rgb;
}
```

```js
function rgbToHwb(red, green, blue) {
    var hsl = rgbToHsl(red, green, blue);
    var white = Math.min(red, green, blue);
    var black = 1 - Math.max(red, green, blue);
    return([hsl[0], white*100, black*100]);
}
```